# How to remove vertical scrollbars from facebook page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, scrollbar

I would like to remove the vertical scrollbars from my facebook page, though I've tried much code, like the below, nothing works.

I have my Canvas Height set to Fixed; I'm using wordpress, if that matters at all.

Any suggestions?

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">  
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId: '0000000000000000', 
     status: true, 
     cookie: true, 
     xfbml: true
    });

    //this resizes the the i-frame 
    //on an interval of 100ms 
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);

   };
   (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + 
     '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);   
   }());

  </script>
```

Comment: Here's my external site I'm trying to show in FB: https://jensfitcenter.com/

Answer (score 0):

The following solution below should work:

```
<style type='text/css'>
 #fb-root 
 {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I added the style directly to my style sheet (minus the <style...>), however, that did not work. Should I be adding this style segment elsewhere?